# Асинхронная работа в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, асинхронность, qtimer, paintevent

Есть окно, в котором будет перемещаться объект по координатам. 
Следовательно, вот такой код в методе **`paintEvent()`**:

```
...

def paintEvent(self, e):
    print(self.data)
    qp = QPainter(self)
    qp.begin(self)
    
    x0 = self.crab['point0'][0]
    y0 = self.crab['point0'][1]
    
    x1 = self.crab['point1'][0]
    y1 = self.crab['point1'][1]
    
    x2 = self.crab['point2'][0]
    y2 = self.crab['point2'][1]
    
    self.draw_point(e,qp,x0,y0)     # отрисовка центральной точки
    pen = QPen(QColor(0,80,0), 1)
    pen.setStyle(Qt.DotLine)
    qp.setPen(pen)
    
    r1 = math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0))
    r2 = math.sqrt((x2-x0)*(x2-x0) + (y2-y0)*(y2-y0))
    qp.drawEllipse(QPoint(x0,y0),r1,r1)   # отрисовка внутренней траектории
    qp.drawEllipse(QPoint(x0,y0), r2, r2) # отрисовка внешней траектории
    pen = QPen(self.settings['color_line'], self.settings['line_width'])
    qp.setPen(pen)
    self.draw_line(e,qp,x1,y1,x2,y2)
    qp.end()
```

---

Видно, что координаты берутся из словаря `crab {...}`. 
Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на клавиши **`0`**, объект сдвигался, делаю так:

```
# отслеживание нажатия клавиш
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_0:
        for alpha in range(0,359):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.crab['point1'][0] += 1
            self.crab['point1'][1] += 1
            self.crab['point2'][0] += 1
            self.crab['point2'][1] += 1
            self.update()
```

---

Самое главное: 
При нажатии на клавишу **`0`**, начинает отрабатывать сам цикл с задержкой в 1 секунду, но мне также нужно обрабатывать нажатие кнопок (например, **`ESC`**).

На данный момент при включении цикла программа зависает - это логично.

Как лучше организовать эту функцию? 
Может быть использовать `async`/`threading`?

Comment: Есть ли у вас возможность опубликовать больше кода, чтобы запустить ваш пример?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Про `time.sleep(...)` лучше забыть вообще.

Для организации необходимого вам цикла, достаточно запустить таймер с нужным интервалом. Вот собственно говоря и все. Пробуйте пример ниже.

```
import sys
import math
#import time
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Pencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Drawing")
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.setUI()
        self.show()

    def setUI(self):
        self.crab = {
            'point0': [200, 200],
            'point1': [210, 210],
            'point2': [220, 220],
            }

    def paintEvent(self, e):  
#        print(self.data) # ?

        qp = QPainter(self)
#        qp.begin(self)

        x0 = self.crab['point0'][0]
        y0 = self.crab['point0'][1]
        x1 = self.crab['point1'][0]
        y1 = self.crab['point1'][1]
        x2 = self.crab['point2'][0]
        y2 = self.crab['point2'][1]

        self.draw_point(e, qp, x0, y0)            # отрисовка центральной точки

        pen = QPen(QColor(0,80,0), 2)             # QPen(QColor(0,80,0), 1)
        pen.setStyle(Qt.DotLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)

        r1 = math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0))
        r2 = math.sqrt((x2-x0)*(x2-x0) + (y2-y0)*(y2-y0))
        qp.drawEllipse(QPoint(x0, y0), r1, r1)     # отрисовка внутренней траектории
        qp.drawEllipse(QPoint(x0, y0), r2, r2)     # отрисовка внешней траектории


        #pen = QPen(self.settings['color_line'], self.settings['line_width'])
        # вместо self.settings 
        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 250), 3) 

        qp.setPen(pen)
        self.draw_line(e, qp, x1, y1, x2, y2)

        #qp.end()   


    def draw_point(self, e, qp, x0, y0):
        """ Рисует одну точку в позиции (x, y) """
        p   = qp
        pen = QPen(QColor(255, 100, 0), 5)  
        p.setPen(pen)
        p.drawPoint(x0, y0)        

    def draw_line(self, e, qp, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        """ Рисует линию из (x1, y1) в (x2, y2). """
        p = qp
        p.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)         

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        """ отслеживание нажатия кнопки """
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_0:                
#            for alpha in range(0,359):
#                time.sleep(1)                  
#                self.crab['point1'][0] += 1
#                self.crab['point1'][1] += 1
#                self.crab['point2'][0] += 1
#                self.crab['point2'][1] += 1
#                self.update()

            self.valueTimerStart()                # <- запускаем таймер

    def valueTimerStart(self):
        self._valueTimer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.updateValue)
        self.value = 1
        self._valueTimer.start(100)

    def updateValue(self):
        """ изменение значение выполнения """
        self.value += 1
        if self.value > 200:
            self._valueTimer.stop()
            self.setUI()
        elif self.value > 100:
            self.crab['point1'][0] -= 1
            self.crab['point1'][1] -= 1
            self.crab['point2'][0] -= 1
            self.crab['point2'][1] -= 1
        else:
            self.crab['point1'][0] += 1
            self.crab['point1'][1] += 1
            self.crab['point2'][0] += 1
            self.crab['point2'][1] += 1
        self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pencere = Pencere()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]